# Simple way to just store IEnumerable of some type into new SQL server database table (code first) C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, ef-code-first, anonymous-types

I'm looking for a simple way to store any data objects in SQL server without defining a table first.

Think about this pseudo code creating IEnumerable of anomyous type (LINQ):

```
var result = from item in items select new { item.First, item.Last, Age = 42 };
```

I'm looking for a simple solution, a function call like this:

```
// StoreResultInNewTable(database/context, tablename, result);
```

I'm aware of EF6 and code first, but I don't want to define an explicit type (class). And I don't need the other parts of entity framework like caching data or detailed tracking database layout. If table already exists and object cannot be stored in there, raise error. Otherwise (create table) and insert data.

Data inserts should not be too slow (SqlBulkCopy / BulkInsert).

edit: I really look for a solution where the result set is stored as plain database table in SQL server which means having a property of .NET type string stored as (n)varchar, decimal as money and so on. Column names in database should be 1:1 to property names. I'm flexible regarding details, but should be similar to EF6 mapping in effect (without explicitly defined types).
No key-value store, no storage of serialized objects, no NoSQL, no flat files.

edit 2: To make this more clear I give details about types in my example:

```
class Person
{
     public string First {get; set;}
     public string Last {get; set;}
}

IEnumerable<Person> items = ...
```

This means `result` is some `IEnumerable<TypeWithoutName>`. The compiler is the only one known the name `TypeWithoutName` but I can use it in a type-safe way, e.g. via LINQ. And I'm quite sure this type could be inspected by reflection.

As mentioned in comments: I'm looking for an ORM that takes the anonymous type in `result` and builds some create table statement with two nvarchar columns and one integer column (and corresponding inserts).

Comment: why not save it into a flat file

Comment: it sounds like you're hoping to use an RDBMs for exactly what it *wasn't* designed for.  Look into a NoSQL solution like MongoDB for storing data like this.

Another potential option if you have to use SQL Server... I guess... would be to create an xml/json representation of your objects and store them in a column.  That will make querying quite a challenge however.

Comment: SQL Server (being a relational database) cannot do that, it requires tables with pre-defined schema. You may want to look for Document Database options instead.

Comment: EF is specifically designed to be easier to use that older querying models *when you know the structure of the database when writing your code*.  If you don't, then just use older querying models like parameterized queries and so on where the SQL is constructed without static type safety.  EF is actively going out of its way to make that kind of coding hard, so just *don't use it here*.

Comment: @rajeemcariazo: I'm familar with that (CsvHelper can help here) but need SQL server table.

Comment: @Kritner: I agree (partly) that just storing data for technical reason might be better with other solutions. But other people shall be able to run SQL queries on this.

Comment: How do you expect an object to relate to a table with properties matching your object without defining your POCO class?  I'm still not understanding what you're looking for.  In fact I'm more confused now based on your edits than I was before :P.  It sounds like you want what EF provides, without doing the work of defining your POCOs (which is almost no work)

Comment: @haim770: I'm sure this can be done with code, just searching for existing solutions. I could build this kind of ORM myself (reflection => create SQL statements for create table + insert).

Comment: @Servy: Yes, but this does not mean to loose type-safety. Anonymous types are type safe / have compile time typed properties. Some ORM I'm looking for might indeed be type-unsafe (using reflection) but I guess every access layer (including ORMs like in EF6) have this when leaving (.NET) type system by mapping types/data to the outside world (database server).

Comment: @Kritner: Sorry if I confuse you. In my example First and Last are of c# type string and Age is of c# type int (not dynamic or object). Will add this to my question.

Answer (score 2):

As I couldn't find an existing solution to my question, I hacked some code:

```
internal static void StoreEntitiesToDatabase<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, SqlConnection connection,
    string tablename)
{
    var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        Type listType = typeof (T);
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in listType.GetProperties())
        {
            table.Columns.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.Name);
        }
        foreach (T value in elements)
        {
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in listType.GetProperties())
            {
                dr[propertyInfo.Name] = propertyInfo.GetValue(value, null);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        string sqlsc = "CREATE TABLE " + tablename + "(";
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            sqlsc += "[" + table.Columns[i].ColumnName + "] ";
            int maxlen = table.Columns[i].MaxLength;
            if (maxlen == -1) maxlen = 255;
            if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.Int32"))
                sqlsc += " int ";
            else if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.Int64"))
                sqlsc += " bigint ";
            else if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.DateTime"))
                sqlsc += " datetime ";
            else if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.String"))
                sqlsc += " nvarchar(" + maxlen + ") ";
            else if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.Double"))
                sqlsc += " float ";
            else if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.Decimal"))
                sqlsc += " money ";
            else
                throw new Exception("no mapping for " + table.Columns[i].DataType);

            if (table.Columns[i].AutoIncrement)
                sqlsc += " IDENTITY(" + table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementSeed.ToString() + "," +
                            table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementStep.ToString() + ") ";
            if (!table.Columns[i].AllowDBNull)
                sqlsc += " NOT NULL ";
            sqlsc += ",";
        }
        sqlsc = sqlsc.Substring(0, sqlsc.Length - 1) + ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlsc, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sbc.DestinationTableName = tablename;
        sbc.WriteToServer(table);
    }
}
```

Can be called like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    elems.StoreEntitiesToDatabase(conn, "myTable");
    conn.Close();
}
```

The **code above works just fine** for my problem and supports elements of anonymous type.

Sidenode: I first tried to "trick" EF6 using this:

```
internal class DbQuickInsert<T> : DbContext where T : class
{
    public DbSet<T> MyRecords { get; set; }

    public DbQuickInsert(string databasename) : base(databasename)
    {
    }
}

internal static class HelperQuick
{
    public static void InsertIntoDatabase<T>(this IEnumerable<T> records, string databasename) where T : class
    {
        var qi = new DbQuickInsert<T>(databasename);
        qi.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        qi.BulkInsert(records);
        qi.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The latter code compiles but raises a runtime error because Entity Frameworkcannot handle anonymous types.

Comment: Seems like the start of something interesting, though needs a lot more work and questions answered.  Right now if looks like you can only do this insert once, what happens if the table exists?  What happens if you pass the same "table name" for competing IEnumerable schemas?  I think EF is the way it is for a reason - an interesting idea you have, but there are already solutions for it, just not (necessarily) in SQL server.

Comment: Yes, my solution is only a quick hack. It not only lacks handling of existing tables but also on other data types. One might add code to allow for compatibility (check whether `table` has a column subset of existing table or whether table can be expanded etc.) and improve code quality (too many string handling => runtime error prone).

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you're hoping to use an RDBMs for exactly what it ***wasn't*** designed for.  Look into a NoSQL solution like MongoDB for storing data like this.

Another potential option if you have to use SQL Server... I guess... would be to create an xml/json representation of your objects and store them in a table.  That will make querying quite a challenge however.

A table such as the above described could be considered a key/value pair store, similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE keyValuePairs (
    key varchar(200) not null primary key ,
    value xml
)
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE keyValuePairs (
    key varchar(200) not null primary key ,
    value varchar(max)
)
```

In the first you could store your objects as xml, the second as json (or technically xml as well).  You would need to query your table based on the appropriate key, or do some really fancy query work - assuming your value's "schema" can differ dependent on object type being stored.

Comment: I'm not looking for a key value store or NoSql database. I really want a plain table in SQL server so people with SQL knowledge can check the data.

I need something like an ORM for anonymous types (reflection?). Will add details to my question.